# Why did Mick Jagger sing "I'm waiting on a friend"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Why did Mick Jagger sing

> "I'm waiting **on** a friend"

Why didn't he sing

> "I'm waiting **for** a friend"

As I understand it if you are waiting on somebody you are working as a waiter or waitress.

Comment: Could you add some more lyrics surrounding this for context? For example, it could mean "I'm waiting *on* a friend (to do something)" or "I'm waiting *for* a friend (to visit me)"

Comment: "I'm not waiting for my lady, I'm just waiting on a friend."

Answer (score 2):

What a great question, you have a good ear for nuance!

I can hear the lyric in my mind in Mick's plaintive voice. I think you caught it in your example; he was not just *burning time* waiting for someone; the relationship was deeper than that. The "on" conveys an expectation or hope.

Your example of a waiter, is apropo in the sense that we can be waiting like a waiter for love or closure or friendship any number of things. Rather that just waiting for time to pass.

Comment: Apropo?  à propos, surely.

Answer (score 2):

**On** and **for** have the same meaning in this construction with **waiting**. Some people say **on** and others say **for**.  It means to remain in a place while expecting someone to arrive or to not take action until someone does something or until something happens, though "waiting on" also has the meaning you mention, where a server brings food and beverages to a customer.

> Why are you standing here outside the library?
>   -- I'm waiting on my friend.

or

> Why aren't you selling your stocks?
>   -- I'm waiting on the price to rise even more.

You could substitute **for** for **on** there and the meaning would be the same.

In American English I believe there are regional correlations.

Comment: Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary (11th ed.) has an interesting thought: “One reason for the continuing use of wait on may lie in its being able to suggest protracted or irritating waits better than wait for.”

Comment: I wonder how **on** is better than **for** at suggesting irritation. On and on and on?